# Investigate correlations in dependent variables: interpreting EFA

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, factor-analysis, multivariate-regression

## Background

I have a dataset that includes 5 dependent variables (different genes expression levels, all continuous) and independent variables (a categorical variable -treatment-, a few covariates and a random effect). All observations are independent (i.e. every individual have received a single treatment and appears only once in the dataset).

After investigating the dependent variables by means of MANCOVA and univariate linear-mixed-effect models I am now interested in investigating how the different genes affect each other's expression, given the treatment - i.e. if and how the dependent variables are correlated to each other and if these correlations change across different treatments. However, being fairly new to multivariate analysis, I'm not sure about the best way to approach this problem.

## Where I'm at

So far I've performed an Exploratory Factor Analysis (EFA) after subsetting the data on single treatments, effectively running 1 EFA for every treatment I have (in my case 4).
-Is the EFA appropriate in this case?
-Is it needed to run a separate analysis or is it possible to investigate correlation between dependent variables from the multivariate regression model? If so, how?
I'm working in R and any hint on possible packages / functions to use are welcome.

### Interpreting EFA output

Given the low number of variables I am investigating, I'm also wondering if interpreting the output of the EFA (using `factanal()` in R) has considerable advantages over interpreting the correlation matrix. I understand how the EFA decompose the correlations in uniqueness and communalities, but being interested in just the correlations I reach similar conclusions when interpreting the factor loadings in the EFA or just looking at the correlation matrix.

My last question is more general about the EFA. What constrains the maximum number of factors to be fitted?
e.g. using `factanal()` in R, in my case with 5 variables, the maximum number of factors I can set is 2.
I tried to search on different texts, but I was unable to understand this limitation where I would have expected the upper limit of number of factors to be the same as the number of variables (similarly to what happens with principal components of a PCA). I wasn't sure if this last question deserved to be asked separately.